# CRXDE Repository Login Issue

Tags: aem

I am getting a strange error when I try to login to the CRXDE Development Environment. Through the browser, CRXDE Lite is working fine.

***Could not connect. Please check your connection settings.***

[image]

I have downloaded the setup from the following link and tried to run all three Mac compatible version but all versions throwing the same error. Does anyone know the solutions?

https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/crx/2-3/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde.html

I have OS X Yosemite (Version 10.10.5)

Localhost address is http://localhost:4502

AEM Version: 6.2

User Name: admin

Password: admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRXDE is deprecated and should not be used. The product was a fork of Eclipse made specifically for CQ. You should use the latest version of [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) with the [AEM plugin](https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/) instead.

You can also use [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) if that is your IDE of choice.